# wget not properly downloading file to directory location

Tags: command-line, wget

I have the command

```
wget -nd -P /2011/ http://water.weather.gov/precip/p_download_new/2011/12/30/nws_precip_1day_observed_shape_20111230.tar.gz -O 20111230.tar.gz
```

The plan is to store the data in the folder `2011/` , but it keeps downloading to the folder wget is called to , not the curret `folder/2011` I thought `-P` would specify this but is `-nd` interfering here? I need to use `-nd` in order to avoid downloading a boat load of extra directories that comes with the site download

Comment: Do you want them in `/2011` or in a subdirectory of your current location called `2011`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues. First, `/2011` is a directory under `/`, not under your current directory. To download to the *sub*directory `2011`, use `./2011/` or just `2011/`.

The next issue is that you're specifying an output file. Since you do that, and the file name you give has no path information (it is therefore assumed to mean "here"), the `-P` is ignored. What you're looking for is:

```
wget -O 2011/20111230.tar.gz http://water.weather.gov/precip/p_download_new/2011/12/30/nws_precip_1day_observed_shape_20111230.tar.gz
```